# Javascript regex for single, double and no quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some html attributes that I would like to change based on different buttons being pressed. For instance, the `width` attribute will change. Im looking for a regex with Javascript that can replace the value within the attribute for single, double and no quotes.

`width='200'`, `width="200"`, `width=200`

EDIT

The reason im not using jQuery for instance to change the values, is because the element im trying to change, is the value inside of a `textarea`.

Quick example.

```
<textarea>
    <iframe width='200' height='200' />
</textarea>
```

I would like to change the value, of a value.

Comment: Why do you want to use a RegEx for this?

Comment: why don't you use jQuery, instead of re-invent the magic?

Comment: I'll update my question with the answer.

Comment: you can still use jquery. Just get areference to the element, do whatever and convert it back

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee, not fully understanding how i would do that. Are you saying i can add the textarea's value into a jquery selector?

Comment: Yes, you can create a new element from the textarea's value. $(textarea.val()). If its valid html, it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var regex = /(width=)(['"])?(\d+)(\2)/;
console.log('width="200"'.replace(regex, '$1$2555$4')); // width="555"
console.log("width='200'".replace(regex, '$1$2555$4')); // width='555'
console.log('width=200'.replace(regex, '$1$2555$4')); // width=555
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"width='200', width=\"200\", width=200".replace(/(width=)(?:".*?"|'.*?'|\S*)/g, '$1"555"')
// => width="555", width="555", width="555"
```

But yeah, this is not a job for regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[A-Za-z0-9-+]+=['"]{0,1}[^ ^"^']+['"]{0,1}
```

This matches a string followed by equal to, then 0 or 1 quotes followed by a string followed by 0 or 1 quote.
its not perfect, it doesn't catch quotes inside the string